# Maclaurin representation

Tags: calculus

How should I find a Maclaurin representation for this function?

$$
I(x) = \int _0^x \frac{\sin(t)}{t}\,dt
$$

Every derivative(spelling?) apart from the first derivative is pretty messy. Is there an easy way of solving this (for example using the known Maclaurin series for sinus) ? Or do I actually have to start derivating and filling in untill I eventually see the pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Take derivative of $I'(x)$ then you get
$$
I'(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n}
$$
and integrate once to get
$$
I(x)=a_0+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+2)!}x^{2n+2}
$$
and since $I(0)=0$ we have $a_0=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for ideas, so here are two hints:

if you've got a Maclaurin series for $f$, you can find one for $\int f$ by integrating term by term.

And if you've got a Maclaurin series for $x \mapsto q(x)$, and $q(0) = 0$, you can find the Maclaurin series for $q(x)/x)$ by dividing through your known series by $x$.

With those two, you should be able to get to an answer.